# How do I convert listdlg in Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

How do I convert the below code to Python? The program creates a list of subfolders to store cropped image parts that came from one main image file.

I do not know what to even try for the first and third lines of code. I have been trying to use 'zenity' to replicate the listdlg but am struggling to get it to run without errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am still a fairly new programmer

"Crop_datDir" is the directory containing the cropped images.

"\obj*" Labels the subfolders as obj1, obj2, obj3 etc. for however many cropped images there are.

```
 %--Retrieve/store names of object folders
 obj_dir = [crop_datDir '\obj*'];        % Line 1
 obj_fldrs = dir(obj_dir);               % Line 2
 obj_names = {obj_fldrs.name};           % Line 3 

 %--Present user with list to select object for analysis
 [obj_indx,~] = listdlg('ListString',obj_names,'SelectionMode','single',...
     'PromptString','Select object for analysis')
```